# Library enabling to use triple store with Django

Tags: django, triplestore, fuseki

I need to create quickly a simple web application - an interface for querying a triple store. Previously I made such an application with Django for querying a graph database Neo4j, I used the Neomodel package for binding Django and Neo4j. 
Is there such a package for using Django with a triple store? I have already installed Fuseki and have my data in turtle format. 
On this page: http://csarven.ca/how-to-create-a-linked-data-site it is explained how to to do what I need but using PHP, which I have no notion of. Since I don't have much time to waste, I would prefer to work with the pythonic Django, already familiar to me.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to work with Django, you're lucky, because Python has a libary that helps you to work with triple store, called RDFlib, based on RDF. [RDFlib Docs](http://rdflib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

> The Resource Description Framework (RDF) is a family of World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) specifications originally designed as a metadata data model. It has come to be used as a general method for conceptual description or modeling of information that is implemented in web resources, using a variety of syntax notations and data serialization formats. It is also used in knowledge management applications. Wikipedia

Working specifically in Django, it's hard to give a guideline because the question is wide. Maybe you can find some packages to help you in [Django Packages](https://www.djangopackages.com/)

Comment: If I use RDFlib, then I don't need to use Fuseki server? Also, it seems that with the help of RDFlib I can interact with the triple store, but how do I integrate this interaction into Django's templates?

Comment: What your web application need to do exactly?

Comment: it needs to be a good looking GUI for querying the triple store. So that the user could query it typing let's same 'Mary' in order to get a presentable list of all Maries contained in the DB, instead of some 5-line SPARQL query. So, so far it should be just readable, but in future I will need to be able to also add and delete entries in the triple store via this application.